# Are there any search-as-a-service providers with fantastically easy APIs?

Tags: search, full-text-search, saas

Willing to pay a reasonable fee to add an externally-powered site search to my personal site.

Not requiring oAuth or anything much more complicated than `curl`-ing some JSON with a secret token is a **major plus**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://searchify.com looks pretty good.

I also recently found out that MySQL actually includes some decent plaintext search tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you're grading only on fantastically easy APIs, I'd have to cast my vote for Elasticsearch. It is extremely `curl`-able. You even create and configure your indexes with `curl`. Just about every operation is exposed through a JSON API, even down to managing the cluster and all of its indices.

Thanks to is accessible API, if you are new to search engines, Elasticsearch is definitely the right tool to start learning the basics. And it's no slouch at the high end, either. You may have heard of Stack Overflow, which uses Elasticsearch for their site search ;)

API design is one advantage that younger generation search engines such as Elasticsearch and IndexTank have over the more established search engines like Solr (and presumably Sphinx, which I don't know as well). The fresh perspective and smaller install base allowed both to design their API up front, whereas the others by necessity carry along a fair amount of legacy design decisions.

There are hosted Elasticsearch services out there, including my own http://bonsai.io which is currently available as a Heroku addon. Support for other platforms is forthcoming as of this post.